# 'Invalid attempt to Read when reader is closed.'

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, visual-studio, runtime-error

I'm trying to write in a .txt file the data from mysql uinlg c#, but it appears me the error "Invalid attempt to Read when reader is closed.".

The code is here:

```
StreamWriter sr_Produto = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Enzo\PAP\PAP\Ficheiros\produto.txt", true);
            bdcon.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT nome from produtos",bdcon);
            MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                sr_Produto.Write(dr["nome"].ToString());
            }
            bdcon.Close();
            bdcon.Open();
            StreamWriter sr_Quantidade = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Enzo\PAP\PAP\Ficheiros\quantidade.txt", true);
            MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT quantidade from produtos_pedidos",bdcon);
            MySqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                sr_Produto.Write(dr["quantidade"].ToString());
            }
            bdcon.Close();
            bdcon.Open();
            StreamWriter sr_Subtotal = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Enzo\PAP\PAP\Ficheiros\subtotal.txt", true);
            MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT subtotal from produtos_pedidos", bdcon);
            MySqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                sr_Produto.Write(dr["subtotal"].ToString());
            }
            bdcon.Close();
            bdcon.Open();
            StreamWriter sr_Valor = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Enzo\PAP\PAP\Ficheiros\valor.txt", true);
            MySqlCommand cmd3 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT valor from produtos");
            MySqlDataReader dr3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                sr_Produto.Write(dr["valor"].ToString());
            }
            bdcon.Close();
```

If somebody can help me, I'll be glad.

Comment: You are using `dr` every time, instead of `dr1`, `dr2`, ...

Comment: Also, you need not close the connection and open again this often. You are opening stream writer for different files, _but_ writing to always one stream i.e `sr_Produto`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your code you are creating your `MySqlDataReader dr` and loading it, then you close it and create and load `MySqlDataReader dr1`. You then try to read your `dr` which you have already closed.  It also looks like you might be trying to write to the wrong StreamWriter as well.

[image]